# Weird malfunction in Binary Search Tree in C

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

My program reads lines from a file and builds the tree with it. From my `main` I call the function `loadFromFile`, which does all the work. This function calls the `insert` method which in turns calls the function to compare the strings. This is the structure used:

```
typedef struct Node {
    char *key;
    int count;
    struct Node *left, *right;
} node;
```

This is the `loadFromFile` function that has two parameters, the first one the address of the file needed to read the data, and the second one the is the mode in which the strings will be compared. As you will notice, I used the `printf` to show you later the output:

```
node * loadFromFile(char * address, int mode){

    FILE * file;
    char * line_readed;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    node * new_node;
    node * tmp = NULL;

    file = fopen(address, "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("File \"%s\" doesn't exist.\n", address);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((read = getline(&line_readed, &len, file)) != -1) {
        new_node = get_node();
        line_readed[strlen(line_readed)-1] = 0;
        new_node->key = line_readed;
        printf("line readed: %s\n", line_readed);
        if(tmp != NULL){
            printf("- tmp->key: %s \n", tmp->key);
            tmp = insert(tmp, new_node, mode);
        }else{
            tmp = new_node;
            printf("- tmp->key: %s \n", tmp->key);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    printBST(tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

To create a new node, the function `get_node()` is used, and its code is this one:

```
node * get_node() {
    node *temp;
    temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp -> left = NULL;
    temp -> right = NULL;
    temp -> count = 1;
    return temp;
}
```

The code of the insert is this one:

```
node * insert(node *root, node *new_node, int mode) {
    int comparison;
    if(mode){
        comparison = my_strcmp(new_node->key, root->key);
        if (comparison == -1){
            if (root->left == NULL){
                root->left = new_node;
            }else
                insert(root->left, new_node, mode);
        }
        else if (comparison == 1)
            if (root->right == NULL){
                root->right = new_node;
            }else
                insert(root->right, new_node, mode);
        else{
            root->count++;
        }
    }else{
        comparison = my_strignorecasecmp(new_node->key, root->key);   
        if (comparison == -1){
            if (root->left == NULL){
                root->left = new_node;
            }else
                insert(root->left, new_node, mode);
        }
        else if (comparison == 1)
            if (root->right == NULL){
                root->right = new_node;
            }else
                insert(root->right, new_node, mode);
        else{
            root->count++;
        }
    }   
    return root;
}
```

And last but not least, the code to print the BST:

```
void printBST(node * root){
    if(root != NULL){
        printBST(root->left);
        printf("%s\n",root->key);
        printBST(root->right);
    }
}
```

The output is the following:

```
line readed: asddassdfgsdfgdfghx
- tmp->key: asddassdfgsdfgdfghx  
line readed: bb
- tmp->key: bb 
line readed: adassss
- tmp->key: adassss 
line readed: zasx
- tmp->key: zasx 
line readed: www
- tmp->key: www 
www
```

I checked independently the compare string functions and they worked perfectly, so I'm assuming the problem is related to pointers, but I can't see where, or how to fix it. The variable `tmp`, that should be the root, is taking all the values of the lines I'm reading and I don't understand why; maybe because I come from JAVA these things are a little different for me. I don't think the problem is in the `insert` nor in the `printBST`.

Comment: Well done (except for your problem, that is). `node * insert` always returns `root` itself and so `tmp = insert(tmp ...)` never changes `tmp`. Should it not return the newly inserted item?

Comment: @Jongware is right. A bigger point is that part of learning to program is learning what to do when the program doesn't work. Get busy. You have two options: 1) add trace printf's to see where real behavior diverges from what you _think_ is happening and 2) learn to use a debugger. Having someone point out the problem for you is missing a big opportunity.

Comment: the root never changes, so it doesn't matter. The thing is that the root is changing, even before the insertion call, you can check it in the loadFromFile method, i print first the value of tmp and then call the insert method

Comment: @Gene, I just used the first option you said, I use printf, the results are there, you can noticed that tmp change its value before the call to the insert method, so there's no point in use printf in that function. I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to fix it, and a debugger can tell you were an error is located, but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: You have a humongous repeat of code in your insert function.  You could use a function pointer (at least after you've learned about them), but even without function pointers, you could write `if (mode) comparison = my_strcmp(…); else comparison = my_strcasecmp(…);` and then the rest of the inserting code is common  for the two cases.  One of the mottos of agile development is DRY — Don't Repeat Yourself.  (I wonder how often I've mentioned that over the years; I repeat myself.)  Avoid code repetition when you can.

Comment: I don't believe you know what's wrong. To know what's wrong, you must know what's right. Assume the file has 1 line of data. Carefully step through insert() using pencil and paper to keep track of variable values.  It should return a tree with one node. But it won't. You'l see that it returns an empty tree (i.e. null) instead. The new value is lost.  Now it's a problem of determining where the node _should have_ become the new root but doesn't. The lines that should do this but don't are broken. Now get busy. Hint: How can insert() return a value, yet recursive calls to insert() ignore it?

Comment: Thank you all guys, specially @dhke and @Gene, it's already solved. I just did what @dhke suggested plus writing `insert(tmp, new_node, mode);` instead of `tmp = insert(tmp, new_node, mode);`, I had it like that previously but the `getline` errors led me to switch it trying to get a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem boils down to your use of `getline()`:

`getline()` looks at the passed in double pointer and checks if there is enough room at that address (indicated by the `len` parameter) to store the next line. It automatically tries to allocate (more) memory if you pass in (the address of) a `NULL` pointer or if the current buffer does not have enough room for the next line.

In your code, however, `line_readed` is never assigned a value:

```
char *line_readed;
```

At this point `line_readed` is an undefined pointer, it might point *anywhere*. Any use of the value of this pointer is undefined behavior.

Now you call `getline()` on this pointer. `getline()` interprets the (probably, we don't know) non-NULL undefined `line_readed` as a pointer to `malloc()`ed memory with zero capacity left (since `len == 0`).

Hence it calls `realloc()` on an undefined pointer.

**All bets are off from here. You are in UB country.**

What *probably* happens, however, is, that `getline()` allocates new memory for `line_readed` (and then frees the old pointer, resulting in undefined behavior).

It is important to note, that `getline()` first tries to write to the address you pass in if there is enough room there. Since your first key is quite long, the buffer probably never needs to get resized after the initial (incorrect) `realloc()`.

If you look closely, this also means, that all your `node->key` references will simply point to the same memory location, which also gets repeatedly overwritten with new data.

If you print the address of `line_readed` in the loop, it probably changes on the first iteration and never afterwards.

You might try with

```
new_node->key = strdup(line_readed);
```

This copies the string from `line_readed` into a new memory location and stuffs that new address into `new_node->key`.

You also need to initialize

```
char *line_readed = NULL;
```

It is also possible to *instead* reset `len = 0;` and `line_readed = NULL;` after creating each node, which does almost the same but avoids a string copy.

*Also*: Don't forget that you need to free every allocated block of memory explicitly and manually. There is no garbage collection. This includes a `free(line_readed);` at the very end, freeing each node and each node's key if it was allocated.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, I'm not following you with the 'getline'. I never use the line_readed pointer without initializing it, although the one who initializes it is 'getline'. I did what you suggested, and the output changed, but it wasn't as expected, this is the output
`line readed: asddassdfgsdfgdfghx
- tmp->key: asddassdfgsdfgdfghx 
line readed: bb
- tmp->key: asddassdfgsdfgdfghx 
line readed: adassss
- tmp->key: bb 
line readed: zasx
- tmp->key: adassss 
line readed: www
- tmp->key: zasx 
www`

Comment: @LuisPerera: You don't use the value, but `getline()` does. If `line_readed` isn't `NULL` when calling `getline()`, `getline()` assumes, it points to allocated memory ([as documented](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)). Since the value of `line_readed` is undefined when you first call `getline()`, this won't work.

Comment: You are right @dhke, but I did all your recommendations and the program still doesn't print the whole tree. My brain is about to explode because I did all the steps without any loop (without getting the data from any file) and with fixed values and it worked.

Comment: The POSIX specification of [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
 says: _The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function._  At the outset, the pointer should be NULL, as well as the length being zero (it being valid and a no-op to pass a null pointer to `free()`).

Comment: @LuisPerera I cannot really verify that. If I replace your version of `insert()` with one that uses `strcmp()` (and add braces everywhere to avoid if-nesting confusion) things work as expected. Are you sure `my_strcmp()` returns `-1, 0, 1` and not more generally (<0, 0, >0), because `strcmp()` does the latter.

Comment: Thank you all guys, specially @dhke and @Gene, it's already solved. I just did what @dhke suggested plus writing `insert(tmp, new_node, mode);` instead of `tmp = insert(tmp, new_node, mode);`, I had it like that previously but the `getline` errors led me to switch it trying to get a solution.

Comment: @LuisPerera Interesting that this changes anything, since `insert()` unconditionally returns `root`.